# OpenAPI Sepc 3.0.1 Validation Error: Should Not have additional Properties :types

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am getting validation error for my OpenAPI specification 3.0.1 with error "should not have additional properties additionalProperty :types".

I see this error in the Paths section and Components section. Below is the snippet where I see this error:

```yaml
CreateUnifiedInstanceInput:
  properties:
    default:
      type: object
      example: null
      types:
        - object
    params:
      type: object
      properties:
        processDefinitionId:
          type: string
          description: Process definition id of the process to initiate instance
          example: null
          default: dd4f9b64-7a2e-11ee-ad92-0242ac120025
        processDefinitionKey:
          type: string
          description: Process definition id of the process to initiate instance
          example: null
          types:
            - string
          default: MessageStartComplexDO-3.0--1.0--MyFormWithCOmplexDOProcess
        applicationName:
          type: string
          description: >-
            Name of the active application that contains the process to
            create the instance
          example: null
          default: MessageStartComplexDO-3.0
        applicationVersion:
          type: string
          description: >
            Version of the active application that contains the process to
            create the instance. If this is empty,

            the default version is used
          example: null
          default: '1.0'
        processName:
          type: string
          description: The name of the process to create the instance
          example: null
          types:
            - string
          default: MyFormWithCOmplexDOProcess
      example: null
    dataObject:
      properties:
        startFormBOArgs:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ec956219-9f08-34a8-a88b-e405767aa81c'
      example: null
  description: >
    To create a process instance provide params and data. For params object,
    provide one of "processDefId"

    or "processDefKey" or "applicationName, applicationVersion and
    processName". If createWith is "id", provide

    only "processDefinitionId". If it is "key", provide only
    "processDefinitionKey". If it is "app", provide

    "applicationName", "processName" and "applicationVersion".
    "applicationVersion" is optional. Assumes default

    version if not provided
  example: null
Instance:
  type: object
  example: null
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BaseInstance'
    - properties:
        processType:
          type: string
          description: The type of the process instance - STRUCTURED or DYNAMIC
          example: null
          types:
            - string
        parentProcessInstanceId:
          type: string
          description: >-
            The id of the parent process instance if the parent is a
            structured process
          example: null
          types:
            - string
        parentDPInstanceId:
          type: string
          description: >-
            The id of the parent process instance if the parent is a dynamic
            process
          example: null
          types:
            - string
        rootInstanceId:
          type: string
          description: >
            The id of the root process instance. The root process instance
            could either be a dynamic or a structured

            process.
          example: null
          types:
            - string
        applicationVersion:
          type: string
          description: >-
            The version of the application that this process instance
            belongs to.
          example: null
          types:
            - string
        hasChildProcesses:
          type: boolean
          description: >-
            Specifies if the process instance has associated active child
            process instance(s).
          example: null
          types:
            - boolean
      example: null`
```

and on Paths:

```yaml
paths:
      /instances:
        get:
          tags:
            - Processes
          summary: List Process Instances
          description: >-
            List process instances user has access to including structured and
            dynamic processes
          operationId: getInstances
          parameters:
            - name: Accept-Language
              in: header
              description: Accept-Language header in IETF BCP 47
              required: false
              style: simple
              explode: false
              schema:
                type: string
                example: null
                types:
                  - string
            - name: keyword
              in: query
              description: >-
                Filter instances by keyword. This filters instances by partial
                matches of the keyword in the instance title
              required: false
              style: form
              explode: true
              schema:
                type: string
                example: null
                types:
                  - string
            - name: instanceId
              in: query
              description: Filter by process instance Ids
              required: false
              style: form
              explode: true
              schema:
                type: array
                example: null
                items:
                  type: string
                  example: null
                  types:
                    - string
                types:
                  - array
            - name: type
              in: query
              description: >
                Filter by the type of the process instance. Exact match. By default,
                both structured and dynamic processinstances will be returned
              required: false
              style: form
              explode: true
              schema:
                type: string
                example: null
                types:
                  - string
                enum:
                  - DYNAMIC
                  - STRUCTURED
            - name: processDefinitionId
              in: query
              description: Filter by process definition id. Exact match
              required: false
              style: form
              explode: false
              schema:
                type: array
                example: null
                items:
                  type: string
                  example: null
                  types:
                    - string
                types:
                  - array
```

[image]

To note, this specification is generated using the `OpenAPIV3Parser` by reading a YAML file which does not has this

```yaml
types:
  - string
```

Somehow `types: -string` gets added by this parser.
Any idea what I should be looking at?

In the Swagger Editor, when I remove "types: - string" manually, the error gets resolved. Not sure why this gets added when my original YAML file doesn't have this entry.

Comment: Which version of the [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) library do you use? Can you post the code that you use to read and write your OpenAPI YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a bug on the OpenAPIV3Parser package. related [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/1964)